# Adding a Yes or No to delete option on a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have wrote this script and I was wounder if I can have it do like Y for Delete and N for not deleting the files but I am not sure how to go about adding that.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Set variables
SET SOURCE=C:\My Recordings
SET DEST=\\XXXXXXXX\c$\VideoArchive
SET 7ZIP=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

REM Compress local files with 7zip
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    BEGINNING VIDEO COMPRESSION OPERATIONS
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
CD /D "%SOURCE%"
FOR %%f in ("*.wrf") DO (
    SET FILENAME=%%~nf
    ECHO Compressing !FILENAME!
    "!7ZIP!" a -t7z -aoa "!FILENAME!.7z" "%%f"
)

REM Copy compressed files
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    COMPRESSION COMPLETE - BEGINNING COPY OPERATIONS
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b "%SOURCE%\*.7z"`) do (
    SET CURRENT_FILE=%%a
    SET CURRENT_FILE_NO_EXTENSION=%%~na

    REM Extract the month.
    for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=-" %%i in ('!CURRENT_FILE!') do (
        SET CURRENT_FILE_DATE=%%i
        SET FILE_MONTH=!CURRENT_FILE_DATE:~5,2!
        SET MONTH_DEST=!DEST!\!FILE_MONTH!
    )

    XCOPY "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!" "!MONTH_DEST!\" /Y /V /I /R

    REM Confirm successful copy, then delete original
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        ECHO Copy Operation Successful. Removing Original...
        DEL /Q "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE_NO_EXTENSION!.wrf"
        DEL /Q "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!"
    )ELSE (
        ECHO Error while copying "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!.
    )
)
```

That is my code if anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p DELETE=Delete [y/n]?
if !DELETE! == y (
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [choice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504%28WS.10%29.aspx), and act on the response.

To offer the user the option "Delete files? yn", use

```
choice /c yn /n /m "Delete files?"
```

`ERRORLEVEL` will contain the index of the value selected (for instance, in the example above, `1` if `Y` was pressed, `2` for `N'). Your batch file can then check`ERRORLEVEL` and react accordingly.

While other answers mention the `/y` parameter to `del`, `choice` is generic and can be used with any batch file for any reason.